# Format date in material ui table react js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formatdatetime

hello im trying to format the date  in my table

[image: date in my table]

i want to format it like ' dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm

this is my columns code :

```
const columns = [
    { field: 'dataInici', headerName: 'ID', width: 200,   type: 'date',},
    { field: 'idSolicitud', headerName: 'id Solicitud', width: 130, },
    { field: 'decisioFrau', headerName: 'Risc', width: 130  },
    {
      field: 'importe',
      headerName: 'importe',
      type: 'number',
      width: 90,
    }
  ];
```

and this is my table code

```
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
            <DataGrid 
                    getRowId={(r) => r.idSolicitud}

              rows={items}
              columns={columns}
              pageSize={20}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[20]}

            />
          </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can loop in your items before renddering the table and format them. You can create a date from the string and then convert it to the right format. You can check all the formats on mdn, it's functions like toLocaleDateString

Comment: You can add a column value formatter in your columns definition to render the date in the format you desired https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#value-formatter